# Site to Site VPN between Strongswan and Cisco ASA

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, cisco, strongswan

I am trying to configure a VPN between a Cisco ASA firewall and Strongswan. From the logs, it looks like Phase 1 is completing without any issue, but phase is giving the following error: "received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify".

---

**Strongswan configurations**

```
conn finvpn
        auto=start
        authby=secret
        type=tunnel
        #compress=yes
        keyexchange=ikev1
        left=SW public IP
        leftid=SW public IP
        leftsubnet=SW private IP
        leftfirewall=yes
        right=ASA public IP
        rightsubnet=ASA privateIP
        rightid=ASA public IP
        rekey=yes
        #fragmentation=yes
        #forceencaps=yes
        #dpdaction=clear
        #dpddelay=300s
        ikelifetime=28800s
        ike=aes256-sha1-modp1536
        esp=aes256-sha1!
        lifetime=3600s
```

---

**ASA configurations for phase 2**

```
crypto ipsec transform-set SET_NAME esp-aes-256 esp-sha-hmac
crypto map CRYPTO_map 15 match address CRYPTONAME
crypto map CRYPTO_map 15 set peer StrongswanIP
crypto map CRYPTO_map 15 set transform-set SET_NAME
crypto map CRYPTO_map 15 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
```

---

**Logs on Strongswan**

```
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA connid[2] to CiscoIP
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V V V ]
sending packet: from StrongswanIP[500] to CiscoIP[500] (256 bytes)
received packet: from CiscoIP[500] to StrongswanIP[500] (124 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ SA V V ]
received draft-ietf-ipsec-nat-t-ike-02\n vendor ID
received FRAGMENTATION vendor ID
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ KE No NAT-D NAT-D ]
sending packet: from StrongswanIP[500] to CiscoIP[500] (244 bytes)
received packet: from CiscoIP[500] to StrongswanIP[500] (304 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ KE No V V V V NAT-D NAT-D ]
received Cisco Unity vendor ID
received XAuth vendor ID
received unknown vendor ID: c1:9b:d6:29:0a:e0:8d:c7:c2:73:f2:49:6a:d6:e5:f1
received unknown vendor ID: 1f:07:f7:0e:aa:65:14:d3:b0:fa:96:54:2a:50:01:00
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ ID HASH N(INITIAL_CONTACT) ]
sending packet: from StrongswanIP[500] to CiscoIP[500] (100 bytes)
received packet: from CiscoIP[500] to StrongswanIP[500] (84 bytes)
parsed ID_PROT response 0 [ ID HASH V ]
received DPD vendor ID
IKE_SA connid[2] established between StrongswanIP[StrongswanIP]...CiscoIP[CiscoIP]
scheduling reauthentication in 28213s
maximum IKE_SA lifetime 28753s
generating QUICK_MODE request 4231731979 [ HASH SA No ID ID ]
sending packet: from StrongswanIP[500] to CiscoIP[500] (196 bytes)
received packet: from CiscoIP[500] to StrongswanIP[500] (84 bytes)
parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 3001395495 [ HASH N(NO_PROP) ]
received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN error notify
establishing connection 'connid' failed
```

Any help would be appreciated.